# Diffable 3D Modeling Format

Tags: git, open-source, blender

I would like to create a 3D model using software development-like collaboration.  Ideally, I'd like to store a 3D model as a diffable file/files in git.  Is there a format/tool that can do this?

Right now, the closest solution I have come up with is to use Python scripting in Blender.  For obvious reasons, this makes it more difficult to actually create the model though.

TIA.

Comment: This might sound silly, but what does diffable mean ? I presume it's the ability to compare/patch a file through version control, but not sure (1st time I see the term). If so, doesn't that mean that any ascii format (non-binary) should work (e.g. OBJ, Collada, FBX, DXF, etc.) ?

Comment: What I'm basically looking for is a something like [OpenSCAD](http://www.openscad.org/) only for 3D Modeling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the best solution today is to rely on a procedural description of the model's creation.  Not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a text-based format such as [Wavefront .OBJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file), git will show you diffs, but they're unlikely to be helpful.  However, if you know the kind of output you want, you can use a filter to customize diff output for particular file types.  [This section of Pro Git on binary diffs](http://progit.org/book/ch7-2.html#diffing_binary_files) gives an example of using `.gitattributes` to define a command which should be used to generate the text which is used for diffing two files.  You could similarly write a script that summarized properties of your 3D model file, so that the output of `git diff` for them is more helpful.

Comment: The thing that bothers me about this approach, is that I'm not sure that OBJ files are amenable to merging.  There are tools to visualize diffs in two OBJ files I believe, but I'm not sure how merging will work.  I expect badly...  I'll have to do some tests on this.  Thanks again.